# ng-show in controller with $index

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have list of items with `ng-repeat` and i need to show "Status" text next to an item on some event (like on click etc.), i found that i can use `$index` for, but can't understand how to use it in controller.
HTML:

```
<div ng-repat = 'item in items'> {{item}} <span ng-show = 'ShowItemStatus[$index]'> Status </span> </div>
```

I using ng-show within controller and it looks like:

`$scope.ItemStatus = false`
How i can get index within controller so it will looks something like `$scope.ItemStatus[$index] = false` - this not works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$index is only available in within ng-repeat. It represent the current position of the traversing.
If you compare ng-repeat to a for loop

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

**$index** would map to **i** value.
This means that ShowItemStatus should be an array too. You may populate it by traversing **items** in your controller.

Comment: If i traversing items in my controller by id how i can add this id to `$scope.ItemStatus` ?  `$scope.ItemStatus[id]` is not work.

Comment: Look at @DeOldSax's answer. Doing traversing would looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/g5cxmf9f/

Comment: Maybe i was not clear. In my case i using custom service provider that show this "Status" message on click and  then message fadeout. So my current controller looks `$scope.ItemStatus = ServiceProvider`. And my idea is make this `ItemStatus` dynamic based on item id, something like `$scope.ItemStatus1`, `$scope.ItemStatus2` etc.

Comment: I just realized that I pasted the wrong fiddle. Anyway. http://plnkr.co/edit/Zxd6VPQFxVmYFL3RuuSL?p=preview using a service

Answer (score 0):

As goreorto already mentioned $index is like the variable i while iterating over an array.
So your status array could look like this one here:

```
 $scope.showItemStatus = [false, true, false];
```

This [example](http://jsfiddle.net/f9fdrqtx/) could help you.